# How To Give message to user that "No Record found" in datagridview control when datatable is empty

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I need little help here with DataGridView control, i am fetching data from db into data table and assigning it as binding source to DGV, what if there are no records fetched from database into DataTable and then it will be empty and it will be assigned to DGV, is there any way I can display "No Records found" text in center of DGV if Datatable is empty, I know how to check that if no records are there in DataTable but Please guide me to add this "No Records found" text into DGV. Is there any property which can be initialized in case of no records are there anything which can be helpful

Thanks !

Please note I am on Windows Application not on Website so do not suggest EmptyDataTemplate !

Comment: Could you share your code that you have?

Comment: And please don't spam Tags. Is it C# or VB.Net?

Comment: 1) are you using C# or VB.NET? 2) remove the datatables tag

Comment: You cannot do it with standard `DataGridView` control. Your options is put label with text "No records found" over `DataGridVIew` and make it visible if there no rows (label should be hided by default). Or use some third-part DataGridView controls which has this feature

Comment: There is often a need to convey a result/status to the user.  Another case would be when filtering and there are no matching rows.  The StatusBar control is very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you're fetching the data (form_load or button_click I would guess).  You can put something in to hide the gridview and display a label that says no data found:

```
if(dataRecords.Count == 0)
{
   gridview1.visible = false;
   nodatalabel.visible = true;
}
```

or something along those lines.  You'll have to add in the label somewhere though.

Another option is to call setchildindex on the label to give it a greater z-index than the gridview so it appears over it.